# Azure SQL : can rebuild index eventually run out of storage?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

My database is 390GB and most of the data is located in one table. When I rebuild the index for this table the database size hits 800GB during the rebuild. The max size of a database in windows azure is 1TB. What will happen if my database reaches 600GB and rebuilding requires more than 1TB? Is there anything I should do now to prepare before I run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dilkushp/2013/07/27/fragmentation-in-sql-azure/) article, fragmentation on indexes itself can consume a lot of storage space. Try to run general maintenance tasks of indexes every other day, and reorganize indexes with low fragmentation and rebuild indexes with high levels of fragmentation. Exclude the big table from the general maintenance tasks and perform maintenance on that table when the general maintenance tasks do not run. Rebuild only highly fragmented indexes on that table. Use sp_updatestats to update statistics.

Run sp_helpfile to verify the log is not consuming storage space also. If the log is big run the following statement to recover space.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0)
```

Comment: i just find it kind of funny that when my database reaches 500GB i'll have issues rebuilding index because of 1TB limit in azure.

Comment: On-premises databases I usually have to set log size about 30-50% the size of the data files, depending on the number and size of indexes. I often see updating statistics (full) claiming more storage than defragmenting indexes. Could you please try to see if you can consolidate indexes on that table and on the whole database?

Comment: Do you mean rebuilding indexes? Yes i just rebuilt every index in the database. Does azure shrink the log automatically for me? thanks for your help

Comment: i ran sp_help, data = 806928384 KB, log = 2117632 KB, growth(both) = 16384 KB, maxsize =  1073741824 KB.. odd azure webpage is saying database is 319.51gb